# Simple question regarding BIND configuration

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

When I ask my DNS server for a non existent domain it gives me no answer rather than saying "REFUSED":

```
#nslookup redhafdst.com. ns.myserver.com
Server:         ns.myserver.com
Address:        201.27.144.76#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find redhafdst.com.: No answer
```

In windows it lists all the root servers:

```
> nslookup fakesite667.com ns.myserver.com
Server:   ns.myserver.com
Address:  201.27.144.76

Name:    fakesite667.com
Served by:
- H.ROOT-SERVERS.NET
          128.63.2.53
...
- D.ROOT-SERVERS.NET
          128.8.10.90
          2001:500:2d::d
```

Is this normal behavior? Does it have something to do with a security risk or a bad configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refusing queries for random domains is an indication that's it's configured to be authoritative only, and to refuse requests for which it doesn't directly have a zone file.

There's a handful of options that combine to determine a BIND server's recursion behavior, but mostly, you're looking for the settings of the `recursion` and `allow-recursion` options.  They're either disabled, or `recursion` may be enabled but your host isn't in the `allow-recursion` list.

Comment: **Authoritative Only** was the key, now it works as expected. Thanks.